# How to prevent the fieldset's border from going through the legend element surrounded by the form tag?

Tags: css, forms, legend, fieldset

I have a form with these tags: `<form>, <fieldset> and <legend>`.

The fieldset's border passes through the middle of the legend element. I still want to have the border around my form, but I don't want to pass through the middle of it.
The problem is like this: if I try in css only the fieldset and the legend, everything works fine, but if I also add the form style I get the error I'm talking about.

```css
.form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: left;
  border: 0px;
}
fieldset {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 60%;
}
legend {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Title</legend>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I guess it's a conflict between form and fieldset/legend styling. The reason I've added `position: absolute;` and the translate method is to position the form in the middle of the browser's page.
So, how can I get rid of the border's fieldset passing through the middle of the legend, but still positioning my form in the center of the page?

Comment: **You have a typo**..`.form` instead of `just `form. `form` is an element...not a class.

Comment: What is this supposed to look like?

Comment: even if I remove the class, the things remain the same...

Answer (score 2):

`form legend{ position:relative; z-index:2 }`

Comment: Oh and you might want to add a background color for the legend

Comment: No, it doesn't work with the z index. Instead, I've tried that with the background before, but I didn't think to add a specific color. Just wanted to let it transparent; but adding the withe color I saw it works just fine. It's a good trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the legend to appear outside of the fieldset border, you will have to place it before the fieldset element, not within it. This is not [valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea), however, so use it at your own risk.

```css
form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: left;
  border: 0px;
}
fieldset {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 60%;
}
legend {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <legend>Title</legend>
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Except that it's not "valid" HTML. The only permitted parent of a `legend` is a`fieldset`- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend

Comment: @Paulie_D This is true, it's not valid, but it still works in each browser. I will add the validity concern to my answer, though.

Comment: Thanks for adding the validity concern